# How to configure my ubuntu to allow me send multicast through eth0 address, and receive through eth1 address?

Tags: networking

How to configure my ubuntu to allow me send multicast through eth0 address, and receive through eth1 address? I am able to send and receive through the same address, but failed when sending through 192.168.122.140 (eth0), and receiving from 192.168.122.40 (eth1).

Details:

I wrote two programs:

1. a multicast sender that broadcast message through interface 192.168.122.140 with a multicast address and port.
2. a multicast receiver that receive multicast message through interface 192.168.122.40 and point to the address and port defined at sender application.

I have tested the sender and receiver applications with both having the same interface 192.168.122.140, or 192.168.122.40, receiver is able to receive packet from the sender application. but when I set 192.168.122.140 to the sender, and set 192.168.122.40 to the receiver, the receiver receive nothing.

This is what my route table look like. If it is wrong, please help correct it.

```html
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         hkcore.hk.abc.n 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
localnet        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
localnet        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
224.0.0.0       *               240.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth0
```

```html
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d0:2b:2c:06:23  
          inet addr:192.168.122.140  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76d0:2bff:fe2c:623/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:109471 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1513722 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:29824161 (29.8 MB)  TX bytes:1186271256 (1.1 GB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7200000-f7220000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:21:25:05:13  
          inet addr:192.168.122.40  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 Memory:f71c0000-f71e0000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:406555 (406.5 KB)  TX bytes:406555 (406.5 KB)
```